# enter an arithmetic operation (ex. 5*4) in c

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that if the user gives a whole arithmetic operation from the keyboard ex `5*4` or `5/7` it will interpret the operation ex `*`, `/`, `+`, or `-` and print the result. How can I read the whole operation without the user pressing enter everytime he puts a number or a symbol ex `*` or `/` and put them in 3 variables?
I tried using:

```
printf("give an operation")
scanf("%d%c%d",&num_1,&c,&num_2)
```

but I want to do with:

```
c=getchar()
```

Comment: So you want to manually parse numbers, even though we have `scanf` that can do that? Why?

Comment: If you want to do it manually, read more about [lexical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).

Comment: because i dont want to use scanf for characters

Comment: i just dont want the program to wait the user to press enter after number 1 ,symbol and number 2

Comment: @user1809300 What does that have to do with `scanf`?

Comment: So you want the user to enter three tokens (2 numbers and an operator in between) and *then* press enter? If so, `scanf` will work just fine.

Comment: i want to use scanf for numbers and getchar for symbol but i dont want the user to press enter after every input

Comment: @user1809300 Why should that matter at all?

Comment: i read that scanf can be a problem when i use it with chars

Comment: Does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329406/evaluating-arithmetic-expressions-in-c/9329509#9329509 help?

Comment: @Henrik Ever heard about `sscanf`?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be "understand the operation ex * / + or - and print the result to user". `sscanf` doesn't evaluate the result of an arithmetic operation.

Comment: @Henrik Yeah, sorry, I didn't read it properly, so not `sscanf` but `strtol`.

Comment: In this case i don't recommend you to use getchar, cause then you won't be able to scan numbers of more than 2 digits (I mean you can but it will be a bit harder).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question and comments correct, you want to read a line of input from the user, where the user enters an expression and uses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to end the expression?

Then using `scanf` should work fine. You could also use `fgets` to get the line, and the use `sscanf` for the parsing.

Answer (score -1):

```
scanf("%d %[*+-/] %d", &numA, op, &numB);
```

op should be defined as char array: `char op[2];`

Explanation

`%[+-*/]` :  this means that you expect for %op the character  `+` or `-` or `*` or `/`

Comment: can you please explain how does this work ?

Comment: I update my answer with the right reg expression for scanf

Comment: can you explain to me these %[^+-*/] %[+-*/] %s

Comment: i am not that experiencced with c and i cant find this somewhere

Comment: What problem is this answer supposed to solve? How is this better than what the OP had?

Comment: could you explain the downvote ? the answer is correct and it responds to the user1809300 question

Comment: @interjay: It's not my problem if you do not understand the user1809300 question

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL You are not even reading numbers. You are reading strings.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be you are right I will update my answer

Comment: He wants to store numbers, not variables so letters should be excluded.

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL `atoi` doesn't report failures, your code is inferior to `scanf("%d%c%d",&num1,&op,&num2);`

Comment: @Let_Me_Be alternate solution?

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL You know, it's kind of pathetic not to even read the question you are answering.