# how to get a mathematical expression as input in c++

Tags: c++

I am writing a program in c++ that shows if an expression (example `98+56*(4+7) < 7-6*6`) is true or false.. The expression will be taken as an input from the user..

Is there any function that I can use for this?

Comment: No. There is no "eval" function in C++.

Comment: @Adela Try [A C++ expression parser](http://www.speqmath.com/tutorials/expression_parser_cpp/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

You need math expression evaluator.

You can try this library: https://fastmathparser.codeplex.com/

In the link you'll find a sample code.

You can find an algo in this link: [Evaluating arithmetic expressions from string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329406/evaluating-arithmetic-expressions-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

No, but implementing the Shunting Yard Algorithm is fairly easy if you are reasonably competent at programming.

I know link only answers are abhorred but here is the [link on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) (which is unlikely to disappear soon) and is actually quite good.