# How to convert condition text to "if" conditional expression?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to write in visual c++ to convert a condition text to a simple "if" conditional expression with arithmetic operators, parentheses.

For exemple :
text : "(((a+b)>0)or(c==10))and(d!=e))" or "(a>b)xor(c==d)", etc...

we have normally in c++ style :

```
int a,b,c,d,e;
...
...    
char text[]="(((a+b)>0)or(c==10))and(d!=e))";
if(text_to_if(text)) { .... }
...
...
```

letters a, b, c, d, e in text correspond with existing integer or float variables.

Comment: There's no such thing like evaluating expressions at runtime in c++.

Comment: Right, of course. But in fact, my objective is to make a function to translate this condition text to execute "real" conditions. I'm studying.

Comment: I think this is duplicate with [Evaluating arithmetic expressions from string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329406/evaluating-arithmetic-expressions-from-string-in-c#27442993)

Comment: @Chrisoft Closest I can think of is writing an expression parser e.g. using `boost::spirit`or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Please mind that C++ is not an interpreted language. You can not change code, including if statements, at runtime. If you want runtime code evaluation you could try JavaScript with its `eval()` function [[1](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp).

Further on you won't be able to retrieve variable names from your code (except for debugging purposes).