# How to calculate a string and store it in a variable?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I'm writing a c++ calculator but I keep getting stuck on the part which changes the std::string into float variable for mathematical calculation.

I've already tried atoi and using 'var' (single-quote) but it seems to result in erratically large numbers and some variations of the code won't even compile saying "Line 13   Column 18   C:\Users\User\Desktop\calculator.cpp    [Error] cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'float' in initialization".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Input arithmetic calculation: \n";
    std::string calc;
    std::cin >> calc;
    atoi( calc.c_str() );
    float result=calc;
    std::cout << "Result = ";
    std::cout << result << '\n';
}
```

I expect the output to be calculated such as 
10*9=90 
but it ends up as 
10*9
or (when adding single-quote to calc in float result=calc) 
1.93708e+009.

Comment: The above code will not compile. You cannot assign `std::string` to `float`, as in `float result=calc;`. You also discard the return value of `atoi()`.

Comment: `atoi` isn't an evaluation function, which you're looking for, it just converts numeric strings to integers. For example converting `"12"` to `12`.

Comment: So what i need is an evaluation function to calculate the string "calc"?

Comment: @kornkaobat [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329406/evaluating-arithmetic-expressions-from-string-in-c) may help you.

Comment: Okay, I've found tinyexpr.h header file which solves my problem.

Comment: Check here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expression-evaluation/

Comment: @Useless No. I just want to migrate from Batch language which uses this syntax set /p cal=  then on the next line set /a result=%cal%

Answer (score 1):

> [...] I keep getting stuck on the part which changes the `std::string` into `float` variable for mathematical calculation.

Because:

1. you discard the value of `atoi()`. The usage would look like this: `float result = atoi(calc.c_str());`
2. `atoi()` doesn't do what you think it does. It does **not** perform any mathematical evaluations. It simply converts text that can be represented as a number, to said number, i.e. `float x = atoi("5");` will yield `x == 5`. You can't use `atoi()` and expect it to perform mathematical calculations. It just converts.

You would need to implement this behaviour yourself.