# How to pass a function signature as input in order to initialize another function in C++?

Tags: c++, function, parsing, input

my question is the following: supposing I have a program, written in C++, which takes a function and gives its integral. In this program I write the function manually, in the source code, and I change its signature every time I want to integrate another function. If now I want to initialize this function in input (for example giving a string), in order to directly initialize it at compiling time, how could I do?

I would be interested in having something like this:

```
$ ./program
$ Give me the function name: x+3y+4
```

and now the function is initialized with:

```
int func() { return x+3y+4; }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329406/evaluating-arithmetic-expressions-from-string-in-c

Comment: Unfortunately there's no equivalent for javascripts `eval()` function in standard c++, it's probably more complicated than you imagine.

Comment: You're looking at writing a minimal language interpreter.  For example BASIC or Matlab.  Not a simple task.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews well, there are some APIs like lua, or tcl

Comment: Code generation and a build automation tool. Write a little program that asks for and reads in the formula and generates a source file that will be compiled and linked in. The build automation tool always runs the little program to generate the integrator and then builds the final program.